# Drupal can't theme password reset mail

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-7

I have an htmlmail.tpl.php who theme all my emails with an header and footer, the problem is that this file theme all the emails except one. The password reset email, it's the only one I doesn't make a custom template file so I was thinking that was because of this but after trying to create a custom template file it's the same result. Theme doesn't appear.

I've search on the web for like two days but can't find any solution, anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

This

> mimemail-message--user-pasword-reset.tpl.php

template file name is not worked.Belowone worked for me

> mimemail-message--password_reset.tpl.php

Found here : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199364/what-is-the-name-of-the-template-to-theme-a-reset-password-mail

Comment: This works ! But with a similar template, instead of mimemail-message--user-pasword_reset I use the htmlmail--user--password_reset and it's finally working ! Thanks